# Installing Sublime Text's command line tool 'subl' in terminal, permission denied?

Tags: terminal, osx-lion, sublimetext

I'm tryng to use Sublime Text from the terminal, for example by typing `subl`.

I'm following the steps from Sublime Text's website:

> Setup
>
> The first task is to make a symlink to subl. Assuming you've placed Sublime Text 2 in the Applications folder, and that you have a ~/bin directory in your path, you can run:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

I keep getting `permission denied : ~/bin/subl: Permission Denied`

I have been searching around for a similar problem but can't find one that's applicable. Can someone point me to the right direction?

Comment: I'm on the admin account of my OS X Lion laptop

Comment: got it used: `sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl`

Comment: I've done this but the subl command doesnt work for me... Just get command not found. Any ideas?

Answer (score 102, accepted):

I am assuming that you don't have the bin directory. You can do the following:

```
cd 
mkdir bin
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" ~/bin/subl
```

`ln -s` will create a alias of the subl file in your bin directory and you will be able to run the command.

If this still doesn't work you will have to edit your .bash_profile. You can do it by following commands: (NOTE: For this to work you need to have done the above steps already.)

1. Open your .bash_profile:

   ```
   cd                  // this will get you back to home directory
   vim .bash_profile   // this will open your .bash_profile file
   ```
2. Edit .bash_profile: press I to get into "insert" mode and add following:

   ```
   export PATH=$PATH:~/bin
   ```
3. Save and exit. Press Esc to get into command mode:

   ```
   :wq   // saves and close file
   exit  // exits terminal
   ```
4. Reopen the terminal:

   ```
   subl --help
   ```

That should bring up the help for Sublime Text.

Comment: I kept trying editing bash_profile before this post but didn't restart terminal. Didn't work... Now done! YAY!

Comment: Why would you create a bin directory in your home folder and then create a symbolic link to /usr/bin/subl?

Comment: You'd think someone would make a "brew install subl" command... no...
Error: No available formula for subl

Comment: @MartinCleaver You should check brew cask. https://github.com/caskroom/homebrew-cask Once installed you can do something like brew cask install sublime-text

Answer (score 45):

My personal preference for the path to the third-party application-specific symbolic links (e.g. `subl`, `brew`, `github`, `mate`, etc) is:

```
/usr/local/bin
```

Why not `/usr/bin/`?

1. `/usr/bin` is a "sacred" place. It is *generally* recommended to store static binaries that are maintained by [package management systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_package_management_systems). `subl` is not this case.
2. `subl` is not *stable* enough to be stored in `/usr/bin` with other basic BSD binaries (e.g. `find`, `man`, `make`, etc). You must modify/delete `subl` symbolic link manually if   (a) the developers of Sublime Text Editor decide to change its app name in the future releases (as [BBEdit Lite was changed to TextWrangler](http://www.macworld.com/article/1042147/textwrangler.html) after version 6.1), or (b) you may simply wish to uninstall Sublime Text Editor.

---

Therefore, I suggest you execute the following line, assuming `/usr/local/bin/` exists:

```
ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/local/bin/subl
```

Answer (score 16):

Check whether "~/bin/" is included in the path.

A better options is to create the symlink in /usr/bin directory instead.

```
sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl
```

Comment: type "echo $PATH" to see the path.  Look for /usr/bin:/bin:  If its there then the above command should work fine, It did for me.  Thanks user1427458