# How to change back to the first_app directory?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm new to Ruby and am trying to make my way through the Hartl tutorial. I ran into a couple issues this morning and am afraid that I might have made one of them worse.

I was doing fine in the tutorial until I got to the Heroku deployment section of chapter 1 and realized that I had yet to setup the Sublime Text 2 "subl" command so that my terminal could interact with Sublime Text.

I then went on a chase to figure out how to get the subl command to work.  While trying to get that figured out, I came across this thread ([Installing Sublime Text's command line tool 'subl' in terminal, permission denied?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10196449/installing-sublime-texts-command-line-tool-subl-in-terminal-permission-denie)) and went ahead and changed directories to the "mkdir bin" so that I could run "sudo ln -s "/Applications/Sublime Text 2.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin/subl" /usr/bin/subl" and get my subl command line to work.

Well, when I entered the "sudo ln -s...." line it asked for a password and basically said I should be careful what I was doing. In light of that, I just want to return to my "first_app" directory and try to figure stuff out a different way. Only problem is, when I hit "cd first_app" it tells me there is no such file or directory... I'm starting to freak out a little bit now...

1. How can I get back to the first_app directory? Surely it's not gone?!'  <-- most important!!
2. If I can get back to the first_app directory, how in the world can I get the subl command line so that I can continue on with deployment, etc...?

Any and all help is much appreciated as I try and work through this really frustrating phase.

UPDATE: **I just changed it back to the first_app directory** -- what is the best way to get this subl command line working?

Comment: does other basic commands work? like `ls`, `pwd` etc? or still they dont?

Comment: Thankfully, I was able to get the first_app directory piece figured out but still trying to get the subl command line to exist/work

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what directory you're in, if you try to `cd first_app`, it may not be a sub-directory of the dir you're currently in.

Some basic linux commands to help you out:

```
cd .. <-- Moves up a level
pwd   <-- Shows where you currently are in the directory structure
ls    <-- Shows files/folders that exist in the directory you are in.
```

Comment: Thanks Catfish - just got the first_app directory piece figured out!